# Zlib compression imcompatible between Ionic.Zip, System.IO.Compression and SharpCompress

Tags: c#, compression, zlib

I am working on porting a file format (OMF) into C#. Part of the storage in the file is an array of zlib compressed data. An existing version of the file formatter uses a static method from Ionic.Zip to read the file, as follows:

```
public static byte[] Uncompress(this byte[] value)
    {
        // Uncompress
        return ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(value);
    }
```

The project I am working on currently already uses SharpCompress and using 2 different compression libraries seemed wasteful, so I figured I would rewrite it to use SharpCompress. SharpCompress does not have the UncompressBuffer static function that Ionic does, so I implemented it as follows which seemed to be a pretty standard approach in my reading:

```
using (var originalStream = new MemoryStream(value))
        {
            using (var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var decompressor = new ZlibStream(originalStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    decompressor.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
                    return decompressedStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

I have also tried a similiar approach using the **System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream** class, following the MSDocs provided pattern. However, in both cases, at the CopyTo function call, I get an exception indicating there is an issue with the data:

For Zlib:  *'Zlib Exception: Bad state (incorrect data check)'*

For Windows: *'Block length does not match with its complement'*

It could be something I am missing that differentiates the function of the UncompressBuffer function from this method of decompression, but it seems like the UncompressBuffer function works with internal portions of the Zlib Class.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a difference between the implementations of the 2 zip libraries that makes them incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

The code below runs, which suggests that there are at least baseline round trip capabilities with Ionic.Zip and SharpCompress. This suggests that there might be some specific subtleties with the payload you are trying to decompress.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rnd = new Random(0);
        var raw = new byte[1024];
        rnd.NextBytes(raw);
        raw = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(System.Convert.ToBase64String(raw));

        var ionicCompressed = Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.CompressBuffer(raw);
        var sharpCompressed = DoSharpCompress(raw);

        var ionicDecompressIonic = Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(sharpCompressed);
        var ionicDecompressSharp = Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(ionicCompressed);


        var sharpDecompressSharp = DoSharpDecompress(sharpCompressed);
        var sharpDecompressIonic = DoSharpDecompress(ionicCompressed);

        AssertEqual(ionicDecompressIonic, ionicDecompressSharp);
        AssertEqual(sharpDecompressSharp, sharpDecompressIonic);
        AssertEqual(ionicDecompressSharp, sharpDecompressIonic);
        AssertEqual(raw, sharpDecompressIonic);

        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw));
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sharpDecompressIonic));

        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw) == System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sharpDecompressIonic));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static byte[] DoSharpCompress(byte[] uncompressed)
    {
        var sc1 = new SharpCompress.Compressors.Deflate.ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(uncompressed), SharpCompress.Compressors.CompressionMode.Compress);
        var sc2 = new MemoryStream();
        sc1.CopyTo(sc2);
        return sc2.ToArray();
    }

    static byte[] DoSharpDecompress(byte[] compressed)
    {
        var sc1 = new SharpCompress.Compressors.Deflate.ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(compressed), SharpCompress.Compressors.CompressionMode.Decompress);
        var sc2 = new MemoryStream();
        sc1.CopyTo(sc2);
        return sc2.ToArray();
    }

    static bool AssertEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (!a.SequenceEqual(b))
            throw new Exception();
        return true;
    }
}
```